# java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation: [6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1]

Tags: oracle, jdbc, talend

I'm using Talend 6.5 to connect some Oracle DB with a few big query.
Sometime (but I can't reproduce every-time), the same query crash with the following error :

```
job.job.my_job - tOracleInput_10 Protocol violation: [6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1]
java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation: [6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:527)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
```

I can't find anything on the web about this error and I'm ruining dry on how to solve it.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using, and what is the version of your JDBC driver?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production` for the DB and `Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 JDBC 4.0 compiled with JDK6 on Thu_Jul_03_18:17:32_PDT_2014` for the JDBC

Comment: I recommend trying with a more recent version of the JDBC driver.